# Location of Database File on Mac OSX

Tags: xcode, core-data

I have an application that I created for Mac OS X and I am trying to view the core data database to make sure it is working properly with my application. I navigated to the correct directory;

current user/Library/Application Support/com.?????.???/???.storedata

How do I open and/or view this file? Is it possible?

Comment: Note: I am not creating an application for iPhone. therefore navigating to the iPhone simulator folder does no good.

Comment: that's a proper SQLite3 database, open it using an SQLite editor.

Answer (score 0):

Had to download a SQLite3 Editor to open the file.

Comment: It's a SQLite file, so that makes sense. You could also use "sqlite3" at the command line. Or you might find Core Data Editor (which is in the Mac app store) better, since it will understand your Core Data model.

Comment: `Liya` will open most sqlite3 files and it is free. In the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 0):

For me there was no way to open the `.storedata` using `sqlite3` or for example the [SQLite Manager for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/).

I always got the message

> Error: file is encrypted or is not a database

Instead I had to first change the storeType of `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` to `NSSQLiteStoreType` instead of `NSXMLStoreType`.

```
if (![coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                               configuration:nil
                                         URL:url
                                     options:nil
                                       error:&error]) {
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
    return nil;
}
```

After that it worked. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117831/what-is-the-difference-between-sqlite-and-storedata) which compares `.sqlite` with `.storedata`